# How To Recurse Subpattern?

Tags: regex, pcre

I'm using `(\((?>[^()]|(?R))*\))` to match nested parentheses, which matches all of the following cases:

> .select( foo(bar()) )
> .select( foo() )
> .select()
>
> .asdf( foo(bar()) )
> .asdf( foo() )
> .asdf()

https://regex101.com/r/BSy6Zd/1

However, I only want to match the first three: Only those beginning with/preceded by ".select".  My idea was instead of recursing the *entire* pattern, only recurse the subpattern, so I can match whatever I want prior to the nested parentheses.  And of course I can't put a lookbehind after the pattern, since it's not fixed length.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a capture outside the parens and then use `(?1)` to indicate recursion on the 1st capture you just created, like this:

```
\.select(\((?>[^()]|(?1))*\))
        ^-------------------^
          new capture group
```

And you get a slight performance increase by using `[^()]+`:

```
\.select(\((?>[^()]+|(?1))*\))
                   ^
```

Comment: You may wish to include [this link](https://regex101.com/r/bujmyX/1/) in your answer. Welcome to SO, new member today.

Comment: Great first answer!  I didn't realize the recursion worked that way.

Answer (score 2):

You may use this recursive regex:

```
~\.select \h* ( \( (?> [^()]++ | (?1) )* \) )~x
```

[Updated RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/BSy6Zd/3)

Here `?1` will only recurse capture group #1 which is `(...)` part after matching `.select` at start.